# Using Dynamic to invoke overloaded method

Tags: scala, dynamic

In C# its possibly to use [AsDynamic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2010/01/18/use-c-4-0-dynamic-to-drastically-simplify-your-private-reflection-code.aspx) to invoke a overloaded method on a subclass (example [here](https://github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r/blob/master/SimpleCQRS/Domain.cs)) thus allowing an abstract class to invoke methods it does not itself define. Is something similar possible with Scala 2.9 **applyDynamic** ?. I tried the following

```
abstract class AggregateRoot extends Dynamic {
  def applyChange(event: Event) {
    this.applyDynamic("handleEvent")(event) 
  }
  // this does not work
  def applyDynamic(name : String)(args: Any*) = this
}
```

used like this

```
class InventoryItem extends AggregateRoot {
  def handleEvent(event: InventoryItemCreated) {
    println("received InventoryItemCreated")
  }

  def handleEvent(event: InventoryItemDeactivated) {
    println("received InventoryItemDeactivated")
  }
}
```

where **InventoryItemCreated** and **InventoryItemDeactivated** both are events

```
class Event;

class InventoryItemDeactivated extends Event; 

class InventoryItemCreated extends Event;
```

I then expect to be able to do something like this

```
  var aggregate : AggregateRoot = new InventoryItem
  var event = new InventoryItemDeactivated
  aggregate.applyChange(event) // should print "received InventoryItemDeactivated"
```

but I cannot figure out how to define **applyDynamic** (in **AggregateRoot**) so that it can invoke overloaded methods in subclasses at runtime without itself defining them. Other solutions that achieve the same result are welcome (perhaps structural typing can come in handy ?).

Comment: Did you pass `-Xexperimental` to scalac?

Comment: @dave yes -Xexperimental is in there. I use scala 2.9.1

Comment: have you left out your definition of applyDynamic for brevity? AFAIK (unlike dynamic in C#) extending the Dynamic trait in scala does not do anything by itself: you need to write an `applyDynamic` method so that calls to non-existing methods will be "translated" to calls to `applyDynamic("name-of-the-method", args-for-the-non-existing-method)`

Comment: How's this supposed to be _used_? You have shown what you have written, which, as you say, doesn't work. However, you did not say what "work" means, except by reference to another language. If you could show the actual use case, it would make answering this question easier.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral I have updated the question so it now is hopefully easier to answer. I suspected that Scala's Dynamic trait worked like C# AsDynamic because its often mentioned in talks on the subject.

Comment: @PaoloFalabella this is indeed the problem, I cannot figure out how define this method so it will invoke overloaded methods in a sub class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dynamic` doesn't gain you anything here because what it does it to let *you* define the mechanics for handling an undefined method. In your example, however, all methods called are defined.

What you actually want is the mechanics of *finding* a method defined in the class, and this does not exist, because `Dynamic` means to be a bridge to other JVM languages, which may implement their "methods" in completely different manners.

All you need to do, however, is use reflection. Scala doesn't have, as of 2.9.1, a reflection library, but Java's good enough for the purpose. Here's how you'd write `AggregateRoot`:

```
abstract class AggregateRoot {
    def applyChange(event: Event) {
        this.getClass.getMethod("handleEvent", event.getClass).invoke(this, event)
    }
}
```

What `Dynamic` would allow you to do is:

```
abstract class AggregateRoot extends Dynamic {
    def applyDynamic(name : String)(args: Any*) = 
        this
        .getClass
        .getMethod(name, args map (_.getClass): _*)
        .invoke(this, args map (_.asInstanceOf[Object]): _*)
}
```

And then do this at the end:

```
aggregate.handleEvent(event)
```

Where `aggregate`, because it is of type `AggregateRoot` and not `InventoryItem`, doesn't know it has the method `handleEvent`. But I suspect this is not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

I don't fully understand what all the example code in your links is supposed to do (`AsDynamic()` is not part of the standard BCL) but given a cursory look at what you've sent, I would say that scala's Dynamic trait will not help you.

.NET's `dynamic` allows you (among other things) to have [multiple dispatch in c#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2011/04/05/visitor-and-multiple-dispatch-via-c-dynamic.aspx). If I'm not mistaken this is what your example is trying to do, calling the right `handleEvent` method based on the runtime type of the `event` argument.

Scala's Dynamic trait, instead, can not (AFAIK) used to do this: it was meant for when you need/want to call a method that does not exist at compile-time (which is one of the things .NET's dynamic allows you to do too, but unfortunately not what you seem to need in this case).

E.g. scala's Dynamic is for doing things like this:

```
scala> class Foo extends Dynamic {
     | def applyDynamic(name: String)(args: Any*) = name
     | }
defined class Foo

scala> new Foo
res0: Foo = Foo@17757ad

scala> res0.hello
dynatype: $line2.$read.$iw.$iw.res0.applyDynamic("hello")()
res1: String = hello
```

(since `Foo` does not have a "`hello`" method, but it extends the `Dynamic` trait, scala's compiler replaces the call to `hello` with a call to `applyDynamic("hello")`)

Comment: Thanks this clarified it a bit, I tried updating my question to hopefully make it easier to answer.